# Does vim provide function parameters in auto complete suggestion

Tags: c, vim, autocomplete

After typing `pthread_` I pressed `ctrl+n` and a long list of suggestion appeared. There were all the functions with prefix as `pthread_`.

But the function parameters were not specified, that becomes really confusing as one will have to open man page again to see the parameter for a function name.

Also I cannot search in the list. It seems like one has to scroll through the entire list to find the function that one is looking for.

Is there any way to achieve above?

[image: vim screenshot]

Comment: Install a plugin with proper support for C. For example, [vim-lsp](https://github.com/prabirshrestha/vim-lsp), [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim), they can show function signatures for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim has a bunch of completion methods: keyword completion, line completion, dictionary completion, etc. (see `:help ins-completion`) and options governing how completion is performed (see `:help 'complete'` and `:help 'completeopt'`).

Assuming you have set `&completeopt` to an appropriate value, of all the completion methods only two have the potential to show function parameters: omni copmpletion, triggered with `<C-x><C-o>`, or user defined completion, triggered with `<C-x><C-u>`.

"Potential", because it entirely depends on how the underlying functions are written.